# How does the Twenty Twelve Navigation Bar work?

Tags: navigation, theme-twenty-twelve

I have been pouring through the code trying to find out how the navigation menu is actually built. In my header I see:

```
< nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    < h3 class="menu-toggle">Menu< /h3>
    < a class="assistive-text" href="" title="Skip to content">Skip to content< /a>
    < div class="menu-main-menu-container">
        < ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
            < li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22">< a href="">< /a>
             < ul class="sub-menu">
               < li id="menu-item-314" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-314">< a href="">< /a>< /li>
               < li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-123">< a href="">< /a>< /li>
            < /ul>
          < /li>
         < li id="menu-item-316" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-316"><a href=""></a>
      < ul class="sub-menu">
```

I'm mostly trying to figure out where the sub-menu comes from. I need to add a div inside the sub menu for some extra styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in question is in header.php, line 45.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
```

This is the Codex reference to this function: [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

From my experience, and some googling, [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034826/wp-nav-menu-change-sub-menu-class-name) has the answer you're looking for.

If possible, would just adding a class to the sub-menus do the trick instead of adding a div? If so you should be able to just copy and paste the code from the above linked answer and then target the elements with CSS to get the effect you're after.